# How to select all tag elements with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question about how to select all tag elements in HTML page with JavaScript and apply an Event listener to them.

With jQuery we can do like this

```
$('td').on('click', function(){...});
```

But how can I do it with pure JavaScript? 
I have this code:

```
const el = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
el.addEventListener("click", function(){

    let cellColor = document.getElementById("colorPicker").value;
    this.backgroundColor = cellColor;
});
```

But this gives an error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: el.addEventListener is not a function
>   at makeGrid (designs.js:34)
>   at designs.js:42

Comment: `el`  is a **list of Elements**, you need to iterate and add the event listener to all the elements in `el` individually.

Comment: If it is in fact a table, you could just add one listener on the table and check the target || srcElement for td.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns collection. You have to iterate over all the element to add the event:

Try with `querySelectorAll()` and `forEach()`:

```
const el = document.querySelectorAll('td');
el.forEach(function(td){
  td.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let cellColor = document.getElementById("colorPicker").value;
    this.style.backgroundColor = cellColor;
  });
});
```

**Please Note:** `querySelectorAll()` is supported by all the modern browsers. Some older browsers does not support it.

Try the following with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if you want to work with older browsers:

```js
const el = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
[].forEach.call(el, function(td){
  td.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let cellColor = document.getElementById("colorPicker").value;
    this.style.backgroundColor = cellColor;
  });
});
```

```html
Cell Color: <input id="colorPicker" value="#FF5733"/>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td></tr>
    <tr><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that not all browsers support forEach() yet on nodeLists.

Comment: @Lain, thanks for the point. I have updated the answer by adding a note.

Comment: Thank you, but my concern was about the support of forEach() in nodelists and not querySelectorAll(). For example IE11 does not support document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach() while other modern browsers do.

Comment: @Lain, I have updated the answer...so that `forEach()` works with `getElementsByTagName` and in all browser......thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`el` is a nodeList & it will not have any addEventListener method. Access each element in this list by first converting to array and use `forEach`. Then attach addEventListener to each of the element

```
const el = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
[].slice.call(el).forEach(function(item){
  item.addEventListener("click", function(){

    let cellColor = document.getElementById("colorPicker").value;
    this.backgroundColor = cellColor;
  });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the `el` so that we can add listener to each element in `el`. Also, to organise your code properly you can separate out the listener function.

```
const el = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i<el.length; i++){
  el[i].addEventListener("click", clickFunction);
}
//listener function
function clickFunction(){
    let cellColor = document.getElementById("colorPicker").value;
    this.backgroundColor = cellColor;
}
```